# Grammatical function of "all" in "You ladies all have to understand its importance."

Tags: adverbs, complements

Does *all* within:

> You ladies all have to understand its importance.

play the role of an adverb?

Comment: Probably more like a pronoun.

Comment: The full OED lists this sense under the section headed ***Adjective (determiner)***, wherein definition 2C(b) simply says *With a pronoun. Cf. **we-all** pron., **you-all** pron.* - followed by numerous example usages. But it's not obvious to me there's any advantage in knowing how to shoehorn terms like this into a simplified terminological framework.

Comment: It's a **determinative**. Note that it is separable and not part of the subject NP, but an adjunct in clause structure.